# javascript innerHTML end tag case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `'tag'.innerHTML`.it will render with adding an endtag.How can i get  **only the display content** inside a selected tag html?

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="current"><a><span>News</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>Videos</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>Photos</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

actually i need to get code like this by js between `<pre>` tags

Comment: Do you mean text content of element? if so you can use innerText instead of innerHTML.

Comment: @daniel, i need to get the display content with html tags like `<div>`, `<html>`

Comment: i actually need to show some code snippet between the pre tags.in your jsfiddle can get content without tags.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this :

http://jsfiddle.net/qGyf6/

**HTML :**

```
<li><a><span><b>News</b></span></a></li>
```

**jQuery :**

```
var pureText = $("li").text();
var val = $("li").val();
var html = $("li").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you mean the text without the HTML tags, you may use

```
$('tag').text()
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `text()` instead, this will return only the text

Answer (score 0):

in pure `JavaScript` you can use `innerText`

```
'tag'.innerText
```